# Undefined error when trying to access Array value of Map by index

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, javascript-objects

My code is the following:

```
let myMap = new Map(
                     [["MMP", ["H1", "-"]], ["TTP", ["H1", "*"]]
);

var array1 = ["MMP", 1, 2]; // array1[0] is the key I want to find in my map

console.log(myMap.get(array1[0]); // Works: gets the values for the given key => [value1,value2]

console.log(myMap.get('example key')[0]); // Works: gets the first element of the array value

console.log(myMap.get(array1[0])[0]); // TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
                                     // array1[0] is the same as 'example key'
```

I cannot see what I'm doing wrong here. array1[0] is of type string, the same as the key in my map.

Your help is very much appreciated!

EDIT: Adding more complete code:

```
var tagSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('values1');
var docSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('values2');
var myTagRange = tagSheet.getDataRange();
var myDocRange = docSheet.getDataRange();
var tagValues = myTagRange.getValues();
var docValues = myDocRange.getValues();

function compare(){

  var array1 = []; 

  var columnToCheck = docSheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

  // Get the last row based on the data range of a single column.
  var docLastColumn = getLastRowSpecial(columnToCheck);

  var tagMap = new Map(getTagMap());


  //Loop over values2 sheet
  for(var n=3;n<docLastColumn;n++){


    array1 = docValues[n][0].split("*");

   if( tagMap.get(array1[0])[0] === 't1'){ //Error here
      Logger.log('passed');
       }

  }

}

function getTagMap() {

  //Select the column we will check for the first blank cell
  var columnToCheck = tagSheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

  // Get the last row based on the data range of a single column.
  var lastRow = getLastRowSpecial(columnToCheck);
  let myMap = new Map();

   for(var n=1;n<lastRow;n++){ 
     myMap.set(tagValues[n][0].trim(), [tagValues[n][1].trim(),tagValues[n][2].trim()]);
   }

  return myMap;

};


function getLastRowSpecial(range){
  var rowNum = 0;
  var blank = false;
  for(var row = 0; row < range.length; row++){

    if(range[row][0] === "" && !blank){
      rowNum = row;
      blank = true;

    }else if(range[row][0] !== ""){
      blank = false;
    }
  }
  return rowNum;
}
```

To make this reproducible generate a Google Sheet with the first sheet named values1 and second sheet named values2. You have to run this on Google Apps Script.

Please see the images for the sample values:

values1 sheet[image]

values2 sheet[image]

Comment: provide [mcve]. Show sample `array1` ,`myValues` data and `myMap` creation code. Make a simple code with sample values, which we can load in the script editor to reproduce the same error.

Comment: @TheMaster Added examples of values.

Comment: **no repro** even after fixing all syntax errors. You can make a working snippet here itself. or test the code in your script editor. see repro of  [mcve]

Comment: Possible guesses: You're rewriting/reassigning array1 or myMap before the last  line. Without repro,  don't think anyone can help you though

Comment: @TheMaster Added more code and instruction to generate sheet. Hope its understandable. Thanks again.

Comment: Still no repro.  It works without error here. Make a new sheet yourself. Follow your instructions and  Load your program and check. see [mcve]. *Double-check that your example reproduces the problem! If you inadvertently fixed the problem while composing the example but didn't test it again, you'd want to know that before asking someone else to help.*

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on? (free of sensitive information)

Comment: @TheMaster Sorry for the back and forward hassle. I have attached sample images for the sheet values, since I cannot link to my sheet or attach document.  Changed the correct value to which it should evaluate on `tagMap.get(array1[0])[0]`. The code now successfully replicates the error with the given sheets.

Comment: @lamblichus I have attached sample images of the values.

Comment: You could just provide `tagValues` and `docValues` to simplify the matter.  Or does it not  reproduce the error, if you simulate sheet values  like that?

Comment: `TTC` is not present in `tagMap`( because `TTC` is not present in values1 sheet ). So, tagMap.get(array1[0]) is `undefined`. And cannot read `[0]` from `undefined`

Comment: @TheMaster why wouldn't it return the values for the other ones that do exist?

Comment: It does execute others without error. When it comes to this line, it errors out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

`tagMap` doesn't have `array1[0]` key => returns `undefined` => errors, when accessing property `0` of `undefined`

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

This is because, property `[0]` is accessed as if it is a array and not undefined.

#### Solution:

Use code guards to check and modify results accordingly.

#### Snippet:

```
const thisMapValue = tagMap.get(array1[0]);
if(thisMapValue && thisMapValue[0] === 't1'){ //ensures  `thisMapValue` is not undefined before accessing `[0]` property
```